# Bukkit API pregening the world before teleporting players

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a UHC plugin, I need to pregenerate the world before teleporting a user so I load all the chunks. I found that this is ineffective as these chunks will unload when there is no one on them. One of my friends suggested I use this:

```
Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Object> map = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build(new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {

        @Override
        public Graph load(Key key) { // no checked exception
            return createExpensiveGraph(key);
        }
    });

    teleport(Location, Player) {
        map.put(new Pair(location,getChunk.getX, location.getChunk.getZ));
        location.getChunk().load;
        Bukkit.getScheduler.runTaskLater(plugin, () -> player.teleport(location), 5L);
    }
```

Also else where I would have an eventhandler handling the chunk unload event for the time that the chunk is in the Mapping. My problem is I have little to no experience with this google API which I am refrencing to here [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) and I'm not completely sure what I am doing wrong with this. I realize that createExpensiveGraph is a method but I don't know if it should be within the guava api or I need to make my own. I was wondering if someone might have a better way to solve my problem of pregening the world or help explain what I'm doing wrong when creating a new instance of chacheloader. Any input would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the chunks in a list during the time that they should not be unloaded (before the player has been teleported there) and listen to the `ChunkUnloadEvent`, canceling it if it tries to unload one of the chunks in the list (and of course removing the chunks from the list again after the player has been teleported). A `BukkitRunnable` that loads all the chunks, waits for them to be finished and then teleports the player might be a good approach for this.

I assume you want this to work mostly for chunks that haven't been generated yet, because teleporting a player to a chunk that *has* been generated but simply isn't loaded into memory yet shouldn't cause too much trouble since loading of generated chunks often takes less than a tick (the delay seen on clients is just because of the rendering of chunks/sending of packets).

The `OnChunkLoad` event is called *after* the chunk is finished generating the basic terrain (and thus cannot be cancelled) which fortunately means that the `isLoaded()` `boolean` can be used as an indicator that the simple terrain in a chunk has been generated.

One last thing: Loaded chunks do not unload for at least a few seconds if no player is nearby (although I'm not positive whether this delay decreases if the server has more players/is using more resources) so while delaying the teleport for 5 ticks allows time for new chunks to be generated, I doubt they would already start unloading before those 5 ticks have elapsed, especially if you're only pre-loading one single chunk (in fact, when I tested this, my server never unloaded the single chunk, only once I started preloading multiple chunks were they unloaded after 15-30 seconds, but maybe this is different on a larger or different server)

I have code written for this that I used to test my ideas, although hopefully this is enough information to help you out (posting my code would make this post too long), but let me know if you need any more specific help with this!